# Copy/move elision in case of delegating to a copy/move constructor

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, copy-constructor, copy-elision

In the following program, the constructor `A::A(int)` delegates the call to copy/move constructor, which both are explicitly deleted:

```
struct A;
A f();

struct A {
    A() {}
    A(int) : A(f()) {}
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A(A&&) = delete;
};
```

Still both GCC and MSVC accept the program without a warning. I suppose that they do it considering copy/move elision rules.

But Clang rejects the program with the

```
error: call to deleted constructor of 'A'
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/MjGMaeGrn

Which compiler is right here?

Comment: What language version are you using?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86849

Comment: @NicolBolas, this behavior happens in C++17 and C++20 versions.